# audio pattern search online tool

Tags: music, audio, search-engine

stumbled upon a piece of instrumental music in a video clip and wondered how I could find the entire audio piece without any information on author/title etc.;

is there any online tool/add-on that lets you search for an audio sample that you are giving the search engine to look for that you know of? or is this something that I can put on my todo list? :P

thanks a bunch;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how these are with fragments, but you could try:

http://audiotag.info/index.php?simplehtml=1

Shazam and [Soundhound](http://www.soundhound.com) are apps that can pattern match parts of songs, but I have found songs by *whistling* a part of a tune in it.